# Bitwise shifting of register

Tags: microcontroller, programming

I am now learning avr programming using c. I have a problem with bitshifting. Suppose I have a 8 bit register named jcb containing 01110011. I want to get the upper 4 bits in vh variable. So, I do vh = (jcb >> 4). Now the value of vh must be 0111. But if now I do vl = jcb , what is the binary value containing in vl in 8 bit?

Comment: vl=vcb, can't be different.

Answer (score 4):

01110011 again, since you didn't do anything to change jcb, such as jcb = jcb>>4;

If you wanted the lower 4 bits of jcb in vl, then mask the upper 4 bits off.

vl = 0x0F & jcb; // upper 4 bits = 0, lower 4 bits = 0011